# How to find a list of values which will be returned by regex and around specific words

Tags: python, regex

Example:

We have array with a list of values for AFTER and BEFORE

```
after = ["start","beginning "]
before = ["end","finish"]
```

And we have a string:
`"xxxx yyyy yyy xxx start value 123.5 yxyxyxyxy beginning valueTwo 156.56 yxyxyxy xyxyxy end yxyxyxy valueThree 6678.56 yxyxyxyxy xyxyx finish"`

I'm having regex: `(?<=\b value )(\d+[.,]\d+)`, which will search for the value 123.5 etc., but I'm not sure what is the correct way to search it before and after the specific words in a specific order.

E.g.

- if `after = "start"` and `before = "end"`
  it should return 123.5 and 156.56
- if `after = "start"` and `before = ["end","finish"]`
  it should return in order, first 123.5 and 156.56 and then 6678.56
- if `after = "start"` and `before = ["ABC","finish"]`
  it should return 123.5, 156.56 and 6678.56.
  So it should search for "ABC" OR "finish"
- if `after = "start"` and `before = ["end",""]`
  it will return in order 123.5, 156.56 and then 6678.56, because first, he should find values before end and then as one of the options `== ""` so regex should search without any end points (by using full text).

Comment: What is "ABC"!?

Comment: @horcrux ABC is a word which is not existing in the string, so the regex will search for the end option as ABC or finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a much simpler solution:

```py
import re

def long_zip(filler, *lists) :
    max_len = max(map(len, lists))
    return zip(*([filler] * (max_len - len(l)) + l for l in lists))

def search(source, start_array, end_array) :
    output_list = []
    for start_word, end_word in long_zip("", start_array, end_array) :
        start_regex = re.escape(start_word)
        end_regex = re.escape(end_word) if end_word != "" else "$"
        for source_part in re.findall(start_regex + ".*?" + end_regex, source) :
            output_list += re.findall(r"value\w* (\d+[.,]\d+)", source_part)
    return output_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a procedural solution:

```py
import re

def prepare_edge_words(edge_words) :
    return [re.escape(w.strip()) for w in edge_words]

def next_value(source, curr_value, end_word="") :
    regex = curr_value + r"(?= ).*? value\w* (\d+[.,]\d+)"
    if end_word != "": regex += r".* " + end_word
    value_src = re.search(regex, source)
    if value_src : return value_src.group(1)
    else : return None

def search_aux(source, start_word, end_word) :
    curr_value = start_word
    output_list = []
    while curr_value :
        curr_value = next_value(source, curr_value, end_word)
        if curr_value : output_list.append(curr_value)
    return output_list

def search(source, start_array, end_array) :
    output_list = []
    for start_word in prepare_edge_words(start_array) :
        for end_word in prepare_edge_words(end_array) :
            start_end = re.search(r"%s .* %s" % (start_word, end_word), source) # the start word is followed by the end word
            for value in search_aux(source, start_word, end_word if start_end else "") :
                if value not in output_list :
                    output_list.append(value)
    return output_list

source = "xxxx yyyy yyy xxx start value 123.5 yxyxyxyxy beginning valueTwo 156.56 yxyxyxy xyxyxy end yxyxyxy valueThree 6678.56 yxyxyxyxy xyxyx finish"

print(search(source, ["start"], ["end"]))   # it prints 123.5 and 156.56
print(search(source, ["start"], ["end","finish"]))  # it prints 123.5, 156.56 and 6678.56
print(search(source, ["start"], ["ABC","finish"]))  # it prints 123.5, 156.56 and 6678.56
print(search(source, ["start"], ["end",""]))    # it prints 123.5, 156.56 and 6678.56
```

Here I made two assumptions:

- if there are multiple occurrences of the *end* word, we keep searching until the last occurrence of it;
- a value that occur after the *begin* word doesn't apper also before it.

Comment: Just thought will mention.... I have fixed few issues, but I think the main one is regarding that this solution will not work (ended up into infinite loop) if any value will appear more than once

Comment: @OksanaOk Do you want multiple occurrences to be matched multiple times or just for the first one?

Comment: multiple occurrences will be match multiple times

Comment: e.g.: `"xxxx yyyy yyy xxx start value 123.5 yxyxy value 156.56 xyxxxx value 156.56 xxxxxy beginning value 156.56 yxyxyxy xyxyxy end yxyxyxy value 6678.56 yxyxyxyxy xyxyx finish"`

Comment: @OksanaOk Ok just another question: if we have `"BEGIN1 value abc END1 value def BEGIN2 value ghi END2"`, do you want `["abc", "def", "ghi"]` or just `["abc", "ghi"]`?

Comment: I thought I have already complicated this question.... but your question brought another dimension. I think the second one is the best way ... as it should put limitation from which section it should search for the values. So if we have `start=["BEGIN1","BEGIN2"]` and `end=["EDN1","END2"]` it will search for these variations: `from BEGIN1 to END1`, `from BEGIN2 to END2`, then when `BEGIN1 = "" and END1 = "endText"`, it will search from the beginning to the `endText` and other way round.

Comment: Sorry, from your last comment I don't understand if the order of the start/end words matters. What if we have the above source string but `start=["BEGIN1","BEGIN2"]` and `end=["END2","END1"]` (notice I inverted the two end words)?

Comment: `start = start[0] and end = end[0]` similar to `start[1]`  and  `end[1]`, so basically then it should start with `BEGIN1` and end search with `END2`, then the result will be `["abc", "def", "ghi"]` and for `BEGIN2` + `END1` result = `["ghi"]` = final result = `["abc", "def", "ghi","ghi"]`

Comment: Sorry if I made it more complicated... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234863/discussion-between-horcrux-and-oksana-ok).